# How to send array to servlet with ajax

Tags: ajax, arrays, servlets, send

Have to send an array to the servlet using ajax as follows

```
// My array "mapTest"
var mapTest = {key1: ["a1", "a2", "a3"], key2: ["b1", "b2"]};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assembles-query",
    data: {
    "mapList[]" : mapTest
  },
    error:function(){
    console.log("ERROR");
  },
    success:function(responseText){
    $("textarea[id=assembleQuery]").text(responseText);
  }
});
```

In the servlet try receives the values contained in the array as follows

```
String[] mapList = request.getParameterValues("mapList[]");
```

When I scroll through the values contained in the array is always returned **java.lang.NullPointerException**

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapaList.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(mapList[i]);
}
```

What should I do to solve this problem? Since already thank you for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have PHP in mind while developing this. You seem to be confusing the PHP-specific feature of transparently converting request parameter names with a brace `[]` suffix to an array as being something specific to standard HTTP. This is thus absolutely not true. HTTP has no such concept. The Servlet API which is built closely on top of HTTP does not support this PHP-specific feature at all.

In your particular construct, those values are available as:

```
String[] key1values = request.getParameterValues("mapList[][key1][]");
String[] key2values = request.getParameterValues("mapList[][key2][]");
```

Note that it's nicer if you get rid of the clumsy `mapList[]` wrapper:

```
data: mapTest
```

Which would make the values available as:

```
String[] key1values = request.getParameterValues("key1[]");
String[] key2values = request.getParameterValues("key2[]");
```

Comment: Hello BalusC, thanks for the help. What happens is that the values contained in mapTest was just an example I gave. I have a function that creates my mapTest dynamically. This function can be viewed here http://pastebin.com/Hhz9s0GE

Comment: So, I do not know how many values will be contained in mapTest. In addition, I intend to send the key along with the values for the Servlet. And with these values (key, values) uses it to construct a Map in java.

Comment: Just walk through `getParameterMap()`.

Comment: As I would receive this value in the Servlet? And as I send by Ajax? No ajax seria <pre><code>mapList1 = mapList</pre></code> e no Servlet seria Map mapList = request.getParameterMap(); If this is not so, as that would be? Thank you.